# getting null pointer exception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to have name of contacts in one array and their types in another array,but can't get through with null pointer exception.here is my code.I have pointed out the line where I am getting null pointer exception.please help..thanks in advance.

```
package application.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;  
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Data;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public final class TestActivity extends Activity {
String[] name;
String[] phoneType;
ListView lv;
ListViewAdapter lva;


    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Activity State: onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    LinearLayout mainLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);               
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();        
    mainLayout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main,null));
    mainLayout.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.extra,null));

    this.addContentView(mainLayout, params);

      lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     lva = new ListViewAdapter(this,name,phoneType); 
    lv.setAdapter(lva);
    testGetContacts();
}


private void testGetContacts() { 

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        String[] projection = new String[] { Data._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE}; 

        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null); 


        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) { 

        try {

            int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
            int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
             int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

          while (cur.moveToNext()) {
             int  i=1;
              String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
 //HERE LIES NULL POINTER EXCEPTION   name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);  
 //HERE TOO              phoneType[i] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);

             i++;


              System.out.println(id + "\n");
              System.out.println(name + "\n");
              System.out.println(phoneType + "\n");


          }


        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
           //handling exception       
        } finally { 
         if (!cur.isClosed()) {
             cur.close();
         }     
     }

        }

}
}
```

Comment: disregard that, your `name` and `phoneType` are not initialized, so they are null

Comment: make your listview like: lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `String[]` name before using it.
You can do that like:

```
name=new String[cur.getCount()];
String s="";
while (cur.moveToNext()) {

     int  i=1;
     String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
     name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);  
     phoneType[i] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);         

     //System.out.println(id + "\n");
     //System.out.println(name + "\n");
     //System.out.println(phoneType + "\n");

     s=s+"id="+id+" name="+name[i]+" phoneType="+phoneType[i]+"\n";
     i++;
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i+" - "+s).show();
```

**Edit :**

Create an xml file in layout folder.

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

now in your **TestActivity.class**:

```
public final class TestActivity extends Activity {

String[] name;
String[] phoneType;
ListView lv;
String s[];
public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.main);        

    testGetContacts();

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
    lv.setAdapter(sa);        
}


private void testGetContacts() { 

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();    
    String[] projection = new String[] { Data._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE};     
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);     

    if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) { 

        try {

            int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
            int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
             int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

          name=new String[cur.getCount()];
          s=new String[cur.getCount()];

          while (cur.moveToNext()) {

               int  i=1;
               String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
               name[i-1] = cur.getString(indexName);  
               phoneType[i-1] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       


              String temp="id="+id+"-name="+name[i-1]+"-phoneType="+phoneType[i-1];
              s[i-1]=temp;
              i++;
}
```

}

Comment: well program has run but unable to retrieve name and type..blank screen is what I am getting.any idea

Comment: That is because you didn't display the things on the screen.You will see this printed things using System.out.println(""); in consol. Try to use Toast or TextView to see those things on screen.

Comment: Please see the edit in answer. I have shown items in listview.

Comment: I tried running your code,but getting null pointer exception at(lv.setadapter(sa))..I am after this thing for a week and exhausted now.please help..

Comment: please see my edited answer. It was by mistake s=new String[cur,getCount()]; and also i have updated s[i] with s[i-1] in while loop.

Comment: I edit the code,debug it,and getting value null at lv,name[i],phonetype[i],may be that is why there is nothing  can be shown in view and thus getting nullpointerexception.any idea what to do..

Comment: yup...make it lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview); instead.

Comment: you will get null pointer at name[i] and phoneType[i] because you are accessing the last index incremented by one,which is emply.check my edited code now and try!

Comment: I have already did that edition.but getting same exception.may be you are not getting the point.the name and phonetype arrays are getting nothing.so what would arrayadapter will show in listview..that is why getting nullpointerexception

Comment: i think,you need to check your projection array.you are mistaking in field names you are specifying.

Comment: I dont think there is any problem with projection.

Comment: the code will work fine as soon as arrays will start getting the values as far as i think.

Comment: I don't think,your projections are correct. Data._ID and Phone.TYPE may be wrong column you are trying to access.Make your Data._ID as ContactsContract.Contacts._ID.

Comment: sorry,i have no idea then.you need to check the way you are retrieving all columns.

Comment: i think,you have not updated lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);.try it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing your String[] name, so when you try to access it, you get a null pointer exception. I would suggest using more meaningful variable names. 'name' is very ambiguous.

Comment: well program has run but unable to retrieve name and type..blank screen is what I am getting.any idea

Comment: Now you're dealing with a completely different question. I an others have answered your question. Your original question was about a Null Ref Exception. I'd suggest trying to find some resources to know your new problem, and ask a new question on Stack Overflow if needed.

Comment: Also, it seems like you're asking two new things. Displaying and Retrieving are different operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your name and phone arrays have not been initialized.

```
String[] name = new String[EXPECTED_SIZE];
String[] phoneType = new String[EXPECTED_SIZE];
```

Any proper IDE should tell you that before you try to run it. Are you using Eclipse or IntelliJ? You should!

Comment: well program has run but unable to retrieve name and type..blank screen is what I am getting.any idea

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer because you are accessing wrong index.

try this:

```
s=new String[cur.getCount()];
int  i=1;
while (cur.moveToNext()) {    

                   String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
                   name[i-1] = cur.getString(indexName);  
                   phoneType[i-1] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       


                  String temp="id="+id+"-name="+name[i-1]+"-phoneType="+phoneType[i-1];
                  s[i-1]=temp;
                  i++;
    }
```

and also `lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);` instead of `lv=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

You should add a condition here:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
       testGetContacts();

if(s.length()>0)
{
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
    lv.setAdapter(sa);
}
else
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: i have tried that index..still same exception and null values

Comment: see the edited answer.make all changes and tell what is happening.

Comment: you also need to put efforts.it should be s.length()>0.

Comment: s.length is absolutely correct...what I see while debugging that at lines[String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
                   name[i-1] = cur.getString(indexName);  
                   phoneType[i-1] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       
],indexid is getting 0,indexname=1,and indexphonetype=2;i think they all should get same index...

Comment: No..they are correct.they cannot be same as it gives column number actually.

Comment: one more thing cur.getcount() is getting value 20,but I have only 10 contacts saved in AVD..

Comment: sorry,i have no idea regarding this.

Comment: put int i=1 outside of while...because of it it write new string always at the same place...try this

Comment: @Jovan: thanks for reminding that.I really forgot to note it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me i it helped:

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);        

            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
            testGetContacts();
            ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
              lv.setAdapter(sa);        

        }//method


        private void testGetContacts() { 

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();    
            String[] projection = new String[] { Data._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE};     
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);     

            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) { 

                try {

                    int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                    int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                     int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

                  name=new String[cur.getCount()];
                  phoneType=new String[cur.getCount()];
                  s=new String[cur.getCount()];
                  int  i=1;
                  while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                       String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
                       name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);  
                       phoneType[i] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       


                      String temp="id="+id+"-name="+name[i]+"-phoneType="+phoneType[i];
                      s[i-1]=temp;
                      i++;                  
                   }//while
             ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
             lv.setAdapter(sa);
             }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();    
            }//catch

            }//if

        }//method
```

Comment: I tried it and able to get list view but not as I expected.first thing I am getting twice the contacts I saved in AVD and second thing name and phonetypes are showing same thing,i.e the contact name.I am not been able to get the types ,i.e(home,work).