# Retrieve contacts names and their types together in a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting null pointer exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036850/getting-null-pointer-exception)

I was able to get the names, but I am getting a `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION` when trying to retrieve both the name and their types, and null values are returned in `name[i]`, `phoneType[i]`, and in the list view.

```
  package application.test;import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;  
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.Data;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public final class TestActivity extends Activity {

    String[] name;
    String[] phoneType;
    ListView lv;
    String s[];
    public static final String TAG = "ContactManager";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        testGetContacts();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
          lv.setAdapter(sa);        

    }//method


    private void testGetContacts() { 

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();    
        String[] projection = new String[] { Data._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.TYPE};     
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, null);     

        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) { 

            try {

                int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                 int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

              name=new String[cur.getCount()];
              phoneType=new String[cur.getCount()];

              while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                   int  i=1;
                   String id = cur.getString(indexID);    
                   name[i] = cur.getString(indexName);  
                   phoneType[i] =  cur.getString(indexPhoneType);       


                  String temp="id="+id+"-name="+name[i]+"-phoneType="+phoneType[i];
                  s[i-1]=temp;
                  i++;
    }//while
            }catch(Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();    
        }//catch

        }//if

    }//method
    }//class
...................................................................
main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please do not post same question again.instead,edit the older one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036850/getting-null-pointer-exception/8036921#8036921